# i fetch image data from database the first record is successfully fetch but when i fetch all record the image is not showing

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

I want to fetch the data from the database from my frontend page I used the while loop to fetch the entire data from the database but the first record is successfully fetched with image etc. but in the second record I got only name and
other data expect image. I used bootstrap card.
all the images here are in the database with proper path.

below is my code: database connection and SQL query

```
<?php
include 'includes/header.php';
include 'connection.php';
$query = "select missing.id as id, missing.name as name,missing.father_name as father_name, missing.age as age, missing.missing_date as missing_date, missing.picture as picture, district.district_name as dname from missing inner join district on missing.district_id = district.id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
?>
```

this is the card data and I am using while loop to repeat the next card:

```
<?php

        while($row=$result->fetch_array()){

      echo'<div class="col-md-4">';
        echo'<div class="my-2 mx-auto p-relative bg-white shadow-1 blue-hover" style="width: 360px; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 1px;">';
            echo'<img src="user/'.$row['picture'].'" alt="" class="d-block w-full">';
             echo'<div class="px-2 py-2">';
        echo'<h2 class="text-capitalize text-black card-heading mt-0 mb-1" style="line-height: 1.25;">Name: <span class="font-weight-normal"> '.$row['name'].'</span></h2>';
  echo'<h2 class="text-capitalize  text-black card-heading mt-0 mb-1" style="line-height: 1.25;">Father Name: <span class="font-weight-normal"> '.$row['father_name'].'</span></h2>';
echo'<h2 class="text-capitalize  text-black card-heading mt-0 mb-1" style="line-height: 1.25;">Age: <span class="font-weight-normal"> '.$row['age'].'</span></h2>';

echo'<h2 class="text-capitalize  text-black card-heading mt-0 mb-1" style="line-height: 1.25;">District: <span class="font-weight-normal"> '.$row['dname'].'</span></h2>';
echo'<h2 class="text-capitalize  text-black card-heading mt-0 mb-1" style="line-height: 1.25;">Missing Date: <span class="font-weight-normal"> '.$row['missing_date'].'</span></h2>';
echo'<h2 class="text-capitalize  text-black card-heading mt-0 mb-1" style="line-height: 1.25;">Guardian Name: <span class="font-weight-normal"> '.$row['name'].'</span></h2></div>';
echo'<a href="#0" class="text-uppercase d-inline-block font-weight-medium lts-2px ml-2 mb-2 text-center styled-link">Read More</a>
          </div></div>';
           }
           ?>
```

take a look into the screenshot what is the result:

[image]

Comment: Check the generated output (right click on the page and check "view source" to see if the URL's look OK). You should also show us what the database contains in those two cases. Without knowing what the database actually contains, it pretty hard for us to know where it goes wrong.

Comment: in inspect element everything is ok and database also because i submit the first photo into another record but still they don't show

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache, re upload the images through form.

Comment: $query = "select missing.id as id, missing.name as name,missing.father_name as father_name, missing.age as age, missing.missing_date as missing_date, missing.picture as picture, district.district_name as dname from missing inner join district on missing.district_id = district.id";  how can i inner join the third table name is user in this query please tell me

Comment: `select missing.id as id, missing.name as name,missing.father_name as father_name, missing.age as age, missing.missing_date as missing_date, missing.picture as picture, district.district_name as dname 
from missing 
inner join district on missing.district_id = district.id
inner join user on missin.id = user.user_id`

this way you can inner join multiple tables, if you want **subquery** please tell me.